# is there a correct way to show borders for a listTile within an alertDialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

is there a correct way to show borders for a listTile within an AlertDialog?
i tried to add a border by setting the shape parameter but the borders are showing in the background of the title of the alert dialog and in the background of the actions of alertdialog
Recived Output

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

```dart
  void deleteDialog(List<String> itemList) {
    Color currentTextColor = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.color!;
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        List<String> selectedItems = [];
        double setWidth = 500;
        double setHeight = 500;
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Delete Key Value Pair'),
          content: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: double.minPositive > setWidth
                    ? double.minPositive
                    : setWidth,
                height: setHeight,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: currentTextColor),
                      ),
                      title: Text(itemList[index]),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedItems.add(itemList[index]);
                            itemList.removeAt(index);
                          });
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(
                    'Remaining items: $itemList'); //need to write a save function here
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Save'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: That code really should give the expected output. It makes no sense that it would give a border to the actions and title as well. I tried your code myself and it seems to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

wrapping the list tile in a container and adding a border to the container worked.

```dart
void deleteDialog(List<String> itemList) {
    Color currentTextColor = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.color!;
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        List<String> selectedItems = [];
        double setWidth = 500;
        double setHeight = 300;
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Delete Key Value Pair'),
          content: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: double.minPositive > setWidth
                    ? double.minPositive
                    : setWidth,
                height: setHeight,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: currentTextColor),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          //   side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: currentTextColor),
                          // ),
                          title: Text(itemList[index]),
                          trailing: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedItems.add(itemList[index]);
                                itemList.removeAt(index);
                              });
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(
                    'Remaining items: $itemList'); //need to write a save function here
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('Save'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping ListTile with card widget it will resolved your issue.

```dart
StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: double.minPositive > setWidth
                          ? double.minPositive
                          : setWidth,
                      height: setHeight,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: itemList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                side: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1, color: currentTextColor),
                              ),
                              title: Text(itemList[index]),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedItems.add(itemList[index]);
                                    itemList.removeAt(index);
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```